# Count with vs count on?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I was reading Rudyard Kipling's "*If*", and there's this line-

> If neither foes nor loving friends can hurt you,
> If all men count with you, but none too much;

It seems to me that here "count with" is used the same way as "count on", which- if I'm not mistaken- means "to rely on". Since the poem is fairly old, I'm wondering if the phrasal verb in question is still commonly used and accepted in this sense. Or has it become archaic?

Comment: 'Count on' is very coherent – in fact Oxford Languages [see [Testbook](https://testbook.com/question-answer/choose-the-grammatically-correct-option-to-fill-in--62f0ae1f7d4b072b5b946090) or Google] classes it as a single lexeme, a 'phrasal verb' in their terms: << **count on**
[phrasal verb of count]
rely on [someone or something].
"_whatever you're doing, you can count on me_" >> The other sentence uses intransitive 'count' (= 'have worth') with a prepositional phrase (= 'in your opinion').

Answer (score 9):

I think it means "if all men are important to you, but none too much".

[Merriam-Webster *count*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/count)

4 a: to have value or significance
*These are the people who really count.*
*His opinions don't count for much.*

He's writing about the virtue of detachment - no one can hurt you, no one is very important.

Comment: That is exactly my interpretation of Kipling's line. In fact I read "count _with_ you" in this context to be almost the opposite of "count _on_ you" in the sense that the people who "count with you" are the people you "count on" or value in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

[Macmillan defines **to count with** as:](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/count-with)

> to depend on something or someone

[The Free Dictionary, meanwhile, defines it as:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/count+with)

> to be important to someone

Either meaning seems plausible here.